# Testing out a regression coefficient through t-test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, discrete-data

I'm working on a dataset that refers to the [Stroop Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroop_effect). The data can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Yf01UaIbUgQXpYb2NhZ29yX1U/view?usp=sharing).

I would like to test the hypothesis that the beta coefficient (that is the slope) for the `Congruent` variable is insignificant and has no effect on the `Incongruent` variable (null hypothesis). However, in most systems including Excel, R and Google Sheets that I use all three of them, the inbuilt t-tests only test the means for the observations. How do I test the beta coefficients other than the manual calculation on paper that is simply a 2 minute process? The wiki page for t-test writes down the derivation for testing the beta coefficients but not the method that can be used to test regression results in some statistical software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possibility using `R`

```
data <- read.csv("https://drive.google.com/ucexport=&confirm=no_antivirus&id=0B9Yf01UaIbUgQXpYb2NhZ29yX1U")
fit <- lm(Incongruent ~ Congruent, data=data)
summary(fit)
```

Which gives:

```
Call:
lm(formula = Incongruent ~ Congruent, data = data)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.9904 -3.1147 -0.8473  1.1212 13.0697 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  15.3535     3.8938   3.943 0.000693 ***
Congruent     0.4742     0.2690   1.763 0.091808 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 4.591 on 22 degrees of freedom 
Multiple R-squared:  0.1238,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.08395 
F-statistic: 3.108 on 1 and 22 DF,  p-value: 0.09181
```

Comment: I see the t now :)

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, activate the "Data Analysis" add-in. Under "Regression", the add-in will allow you to run t-tests for the regression coefficients. Having that said, t-test may or may not be appropriate for your data. It is valid only if

1) residuals are normal (Gaussian)

or

2) the sample size is large.

Comment: Would you recommend a z-test for this data? It also has two outliers that I've already removed.

Comment: Z-test is even less appropriate if neither of the two conditions holds... Take a look at nonparametric tests and bootstrap.

Comment: It surely is and seldom used. The `summary(lm(fit))` is the way to go.